# dependent property in WPF -- how do I bind to it?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Suppose I have the following code in a WPF UserControl. I want to bind to `Asset.ChildProperty`. It doesn't work presently because I don't get notifications when the Asset property changes. How do I arrange things so that notifications trigger for the Asset property whenever AssetID changes?

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AssetIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AssetId", typeof(string), typeof(GaugeBaseControl));

[Browsable(false), DataMember]
public string AssetId
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(AssetIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AssetIdProperty, value); }
}

[DisplayName("Asset Item"), Category("Value Binding")]
public AssetViewModel Asset
{
    get { return Manager.Models.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Model.UniqueId == AssetId); }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            AssetId = string.Empty;
        else
            AssetId = value.Model.UniqueId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when `Asset` changes (in the setter method).

Comment: So is there any conflict of interest in implementing that on a DependencyObject?

Comment: And isn't the point of the DependencyOjbect that you don't have to implement that interface?

Comment: DependencyObject allows you to define DependencyProperties which can be used as binding targets.  It doesn't do anything in the way of change notification.  You have to add that on yourself.  See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a callback method in the `PropertyMetadata` of the `DependencyProperty` to be called when the value of a `DependencyProperty` changes and raise a `PropertyChanged` event from that callback method.

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MyClass ()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool State
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); } 
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "State", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(MyClass),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                false, // Default value
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDependencyPropertyChange)));

    private static void OnDependencyPropertyChange(
        DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(d, 
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e.Property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

If you raising `PropertyChanged` events from the `State` property's setter then they will not fire when the property is bound because bindings invoke `StateProperty` directly, not `State`.